# Scraping ASPX with cURL - results from subsequent pages

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, pagination, screen-scraping

I am building a web scraper using PHP curl methods to scrape results from an ASPX page. I successfully got it to scrape the first results page but the problem arises when I try to get the results from subsequent pages I get a runtime error.

I looked through all the hidden fields and only found __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION and I update those values. I am not sure why I am getting this runtime error.

```
$url = "";

$results_page = scrape($url,'',"","");

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $results_page, $viewstate);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $results_page, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];

echo $results_page;
sleep(rand(3,5)); 

 // get next results page 
echo $results_page = scrape($url,'',$viewstate,$eventValidation);



function scrape($url,$zip,$v1,$v2) {
$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';
$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); // file to write request header for debug purpose

/**    Get __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION */
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(!$v1){
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);
$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];
}
/** Start form submit process */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['__EVENTTARGET'] = "";
$postfields['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = "";
if($v1){$viewstate = $v1;$eventValidation=$v2;}
$postfields['__VIEWSTATE'] = $viewstate;
$postfields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $eventValidation;
$postfields['zip'] = $zip;
$postfields['county'] = '';
$postfields['POISearch'] = "agent";
if($v1){
$postfields['method'] = "query";
$postfields['pager'] = "nextData";
$postfields['searchType'] = "agent";}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Do you have permission to access the site in this fashion? Depending on what you're doing with the information, you're risking copyright infringement and even possibly "Unauthorized Access to a Computer System". If there is not a published API, you should question what you're doing. In any case, don't use regex to parse HTML -- it is bound to fail. Look in to DomDocument. Not the cause of your stated bug, but if you work with bad practices in your code, you get bad results. GIGO

Comment: Is the runtime error from their server, or in your PHP code? The difference is important.

Comment: Chris is right that using regex to parse html is a red flag. Other than that though don't listen to him. Here's a (somewhat) relevant [blog post](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/introducing-pgbrowser.html)